# Blazor Overwrite InputText class (Remove "Modified Valid")

Tags: validation, blazor

Trying to overwrite InputText class.

Onblur I call method to assign value to @currentFolderClass that calls my API.

```html
<InputText Id="currentfolder" @onblur="validateFolder" @bind-Value="_fld.CurrentFolder" class="@currentFolderClass" />

if (!isValid) currentFolderClass = "form-control invalid";
```

Blazor however adds "modified valid" to the end of currentFolderClass, even though the server validation fails.  So it becomes `form-control invalid modified valid`

How do I overwrite the entire cssClass? I don't want "modified valid" to be added by the framework.

Comment: You should not set the class by yourself but use [EditContext.NotifyFieldChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.forms.editcontext.notifyfieldchanged?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev16.query%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.EditContext.NotifyFieldChanged);k(SolutionItemsProject);k(SolutionItemsProject);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: NotifyFieldChanged only tells me the field that has changed.  I am after overriting the FieldCssClass of EditContext.  So I can change "valid" to "invalid".  That's what I want to happen.

Comment: NotifyFieldChanged validates the field, if it's invalid the class will switch to invalid as well

Comment: I added the following for the server validate API call:
validationErrors.Add(field, "Error!");
MyEditContext.NotifyValidationStateChanged();

This causes MyEditContext.Validate() to be false.  Which is correct.

However, NotifyFieldChanged does not change the Class to "modified invalid".  The Class changes to "modified valid" even though MyEditContext.Validate() is false.

The client side validation works correctly, but not the server side validation.

Comment: I fixed this entire issue using JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync.  Set the class using js.  I know it's not really the recommended thing to do in blazor, but I didn't see another way using server side code.